# Multi Tenant db - security and filtering by tenant

Tags: node.js, postgresql, multi-tenant

We are building an app to serve multiple tenants.  It's running on a Postgresql database.
We plan on using the same db/schema/architecture for each tenant.

This means when we make requests for data each query needs to be filtered by the tenant id to only return the specified tenant's data.

Overarching Question:
What is the best way to do this to return the data the quickest, without jeopardising security.

What is the best option to "obtain" the tenant UUID for each call? Some options I've been toying around with is:

1. After authentication, store user's tenant UUID into local storage, then pass this with each call?
2. Server side, have a generic function that does a user look up to obtain the tenant UUID, then pass this to the db query functions.

What is the best option to "filter" the data by the tenant UUID?  Assuming I have the tenant UUID at db query time, some options I've been thinking of:

1. Add in the tenant UUID as a db filter query.
2. Get all data ie (SELECT * FROM TABLE), then filter the data by tenant UUID using lodash before returning data to client side.

Comment: 1. **Trusting the 'tenant ID' from the user blindly is _insecure_.** (The term "local storage" has multiple meanings.) This is no different than trusting a user that says that they "are an admin". Authentication/authorization + server-side storage (using client-held protected secrets is 'harder to do right') should generally be used. 2. **Do the filtering _as close to the DB as possible_**, in the SQL Data-Access Layer. Otherwise scalability will be drastically reduced as the number of tenants increases. This is *especially important* when JOINs are used; and JOINs are what make SQL useful..

Comment: Wrt #2. even in a shared MT DB design there are probably going to be a number of "non-root" tables that might not event have the "Tenant ID" included in them directly, much less as a primary index.

Comment: https://medium.com/@mohamedsameer72/how-we-build-the-multi-tenant-saas-product-using-node-postgres-sequelize-c66a085a42ce

Answer (score 1):

- When user is authenticated, you would **set a session cookie** on their browser. You would also store tenant id and other such stuff in **session variables on server**
- When user makes next request you use the session cookie to validate session, **retrieve tenant id from server session vars**.
- Use this session tenant id to pass onto your queries.
- The tenant id would need to be added to many tables and may also need to be part of many indexes. So I would advice against using UUID for your tenant id. Use a numeric field instead. If you want to expose your tenant id to your users, you can convert the numeric tenant id to a UUID and expose that.